# Understanding c++ Code: Tower of Hanoi using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

i am learning about recursion in c++ but have been stumped by the following c++ code used to solve the Tower Of Hanoi problem.

```
void Hanoi(int m, string start, string middle, string end){
    cout << "m is equal to: " << m << endl;
    if(m == 1){
        cout << "Move Disc " << " from " << start << "  to " << end << endl;
    }
    else{
        Hanoi(m-1,start,end,middle);
        cout << "Move disc " << m << " from " << start << " to " << end << endl;
        Hanoi(m-1,middle,start,end);
    }
}
int main(){
    int discs = 3;
    Hanoi(discs, "start","middle","end");

}
```

the output of the code is as follows:

```
m is equal to: 3
m is equal to: 2
m is equal to: 1
Move Disc  from start  to end
Move disc 2 from start to middle
m is equal to: 1
Move Disc  from end  to middle
Move disc 3 from start to end
m is equal to: 2
m is equal to: 1
Move Disc  from middle  to start
Move disc 2 from middle to end
m is equal to: 1
Move Disc  from start  to end
```

My general problem is i don't understand how the recursion is working.  why doe m go to 1 before it executes the "if" statement? how does m go back to 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you print it as a tree you get somthing like this:

```
main
  |--> hanoi(3, ...)
  |      |
  |      |--> hanoi(2, ...)
  |      |     |
  |      |     |--> hanoi(1, ...)
  |      |     |--> hanoi(1, ...)
  |      |<----|
  |      |--> hanoi(2, ...)
  |      |     |
  |      |     |--> hanoi(1, ...)
  |      |     |--> hanoi(1, ...)
  |      |<----|
  |<-----|
  |
```

For each call to `hanoi(m, ...)` it will keep call hanoi(m - 1, ...) twice unless m == 1. In the first call it will call again call hanoi(m - 1, ...) ... until m is 1.

So going backwards when m is 2 it will call hanoi(1, ...) twice in a row:

```
   hanoi(2, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
```

When m is 3 it will call hanoi(2, ...) twice in a row, hence:

```
hanoi(3, ...)
   hanoi(2, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
   hanoi(2, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
      hanoi(1, ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the first part of the output:

`m is equal to: 3
m is equal to: 2
m is equal to: 1`

The `Hanoi` function is first called like this: `Hanoi(3)`.
Since `m != 1` in this case, we will call `Hanoi(m-1)` again.  This will produce the output above.  We are now 3 levels deep in this function.

Since `m == 1`, we will now see this output:
`Move Disc  from start  to end`.

Now, we exit the deepest function and pop back to level 2 of our function call stack.  Now we output:
`Move disc 2 from start to middle`.

Answer (score 1):

This trace should help you, if it doesn't then you can always find more traces by googling "Tower of Hanoi recursion program trace"

[image: Program trace]

You can also find how the algorithm works at https://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2015/12/tower-of-hanoi.html

Answer (score -2):

Your goal is to move all disks to another place.

- To solve the puzzle you need to move the tower from position 1 to position 2.
- In order to do that you need to move the largest disk from position 1 to position 2.
- To do that position 2 needs to be empty and all other disks needs to be at position 3 (as a tower of size m-1).
- So you need to solve the puzzle for size m-1 (move tower of size m-1 from position 1 to 3). This the the first recursive call.
- Now you can move the largest disk from position 1 to position 2.
  This the the output between the recursive function calls.
- Now you need to move the tower of size m-1 from position 3 to position 2.
- So you need to solve the puzzle for size m-1 again (move tower of size m-1 from position 3 to 2). This is the 2nd recursive function call.

The only problem size you can solve without this recursion is to move tower of size 1 to another place, because there can't be any disk on top and you can move in on top of any other disk. This is the reason that m has to be 1 before you can execute the if statement.